# AWS Signature v4 Parameters creating a signature

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have seen this solution by Amazon : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html

but i didn't understand what is the parameters they want there (Except kSecret):
**List of the parameters:**
kSecret
kDate
kRegion 
kService 
kSigning

Can someone explain me please? 
thanks you guys

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you are pointing to is how to derive a signing key based upon the secret key. Take a look at their example code for calculating the signature.  Perhaps that will help you understand.  Each of the "k" arguments they are creating is an HMAC of the previously calculated value and the next value in the key.

```
static byte[] HmacSHA256(String data, byte[] key) throws Exception  {
     String algorithm="HmacSHA256";
     Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
     mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, algorithm));
     return mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF8"));
}

static byte[] getSignatureKey(String key, String dateStamp, String regionName, String serviceName) throws Exception  {
     byte[] kSecret = ("AWS4" + key).getBytes("UTF8");
     byte[] kDate    = HmacSHA256(dateStamp, kSecret);
     byte[] kRegion  = HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
     byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
     byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);
     return kSigning;
}
```

So first they take the secret key with `AWS4` prepended and use that as the key to HMAC the date in the format `YYYYMMDD` (per documentation).

Next, they take the resulting HMAC and use that as the key to HMAC the region name `us-east-1` for example.

Next, they take the resulting HMAC and use that as the key to HMAC the service name `ec2` for example.

Finally, they take the resulting HMAC and use that as key to HMAC `aws4_request`.  The resulting key is your derived signing key.

Once you have the signing key you can generate a signature for the request as follows:

```
signature = HexEncode(HMAC(derived-signing-key, string-to-sign))
```

Instructions on applying the signature to the request can be found here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-add-signature-to-request.html